# Import mesh in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to import a mesh as vertices and faces (connectivity list) in python. Possibly supporting mixed tri/quad meshes.

I don't have any particular requirement on the format of the mesh, as from the CAD software (Rhino) I can export several different formats, including *.stl, *.obj, *.fbx, etc.

I tried different packages as numpy-stl, trimesh, pymesh, but couldn't find any one working. Some of these are completely bugged, other does not allow you (or I couldn't find how) generate the connectivity list.

Is there any package for python that allows to do so?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/numpy-stl/ , https://pypi.org/project/PyWavefront/

Comment: **As it is clearly stated in the question** I've already tried numpy-stl. If you think that it can be used for the purpose, could you please add an answer indicating _how_?